# How to add Jquery DataTables onto asp.net's GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I know this question is asked quite a lot, and I've tried to apply the fixes that I've seen people recommend but it won't seem to work for my grid view when I'd try it.

The datatables applies to other regular tables I write myself, but it won't add it to the gridview.

The code I use for the subcomputing.aspx page is

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="subComputing.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebEnterprise.Pages.Departments.Computing.subComputing" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#computingPostGridView").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
        });
    </script>

<div  class="jumbotron">

    <asp:GridView ID="computingPostGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="computingPostGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="506px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="postTitle" HeaderText="postTitle" SortExpression="postTitle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="postCategory" HeaderText="postCategory" SortExpression="postCategory" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="postDate" HeaderText="postDate" SortExpression="postDate" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [postTitle], [postCategory], [postDate] FROM [Posts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  <br />

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Try adding a class to your grid `dataTable` then simply calling `$(".dataTable").dataTable()`

Comment: @Jcruz so I'd replace my whole function script with that line? if so, it changes the look of my grid view and actually adds a header row with the column names to it, but it doesn't add any of the other datatable features

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Thank you very much, that was one of the posts that I never saw but it worked for me perfectly! sorry for the duplicate question